# Как достать имя кнопки при нажатии на нее

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь понять. На сайте много одинаковых кнопок с одинаковыми классами и т.д. Полностью идентичны кроме содержимого кнопок. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, взять в переменную именно данные из той, на которую нажал

Answer (score 0):

Можно повесить слушатель на контейнер, в котором находятся все кнопки, и при клике проверять, имеет ли нажатый элемент класс кнопки, если имеет, то проводить над ним какие-нибудь действия. В примере кнопка меняет цвет и выводится модальное окно с текстом кнопки:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons'); //Получаем контейнер кнопок

buttons.addEventListener('click', function(event) { //Вешаем обработчик на контейнер с кнопками

  if (event.target.closest('button')) { //Если нажатый элемент оказался кнопкой, то продолжаем выполнение кода

    const targetButton = event.target;
    targetButton.classList.toggle('active') //Добавление или удаление класса при клике
    alert(targetButton.textContent) //Вывод текста кнопки
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button">Кнопка 1</button>
  <button class="button">Кнопка 2</button>
  <button class="button">Кнопка 3</button>
  <button class="button">Кнопка 4</button>
  <button class="button">Кнопка 5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Очень интересный способ, но не подскажете, как бы сделать так, чтобы не кнопка менялась, а брался текст из кнопки? Как то через value может прописать?

Comment: Для этого необходимо использовать textContent